# Featured on Meta is not showing [featured] meta articles

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, featured-tag

If you go to [Code Golf SE main](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), the only post that is listed on **Featured on Meta** is the one featured on Mother Meta. But [the site actually has two more `featured` posts on its own meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured). They were showing correctly in the said list before the brief maintenance today.

<s>Tried to check if it has hit other sites too, but couldn't (I checked SO, Math, Puzzling, Code Review but none of them had site-specific [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts at this moment).</s> [Workspace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions) and [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) are showing their own [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts correctly, but I'm leaving this report in case there are some other sites having the same issue.

Comment: The cast your vote one actually isn't featured. There's no tag on the post. The bug there is that the locking of the post has prevented the system from recognizing the tag was removed.

Comment: @Catija I'm aware of that bug. This report is about the two other featured posts.

Comment: The locked post could be linked to the issue. It's at least worth mentioning in the report.

Comment: Hot Meta posts aren't showing on Arqade either. We should have about 5-6 at the moment with all the activity that's been happening.

Comment: Now CG.SE has Featured on Meta back, but Hot Meta Posts are still not showing (as Robotnik mentioned). It might be a separate issue though.

Comment: @Catija The bug around the Best Ofs [isn't anything new](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17828/66833), and appears to come from the fact that it was unfeatured while it was locked. I [asked one of our mods](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=57437759#57437759) to repeat what Dennis commented in that bug report ([unlocking then relocking](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/20638/revisions)) but it doesn't seem to have worked