# Behaviour of 'Featured on Meta' list

Tags: support, per-site-meta, featured-tag

I just added the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to [this post](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/should-we-limit-community-bot-bumping-of-questions) on the Arts & Crafts Meta, but it doesn't show up in the 'Featured on Meta' box on [the main site](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/).

Is this normal behaviour?
Is there a kind of hierarchical system in place, that the three featured Mother Meta posts have precedence over the one from our Meta (based on views or so)?
**How are the 'Featured on Meta' contents generated?**

This issue is similar to the one raised in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362635/featured-on-meta-is-not-showing-featured-meta-articles), but there it might have had to do with at least one of the posts having been locked. Regardless, I figured I'd ask after the general behaviour, and try to reason backwards from there.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @Luuklag So that's it?

Comment: Most likely, the featured on meta is one of the most heavily cached parts of the site. For me it shows up in the box on the main site now.

Comment: As Catija said in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342538/how-or-when-is-the-featured-tag-supposed-to-take-effect#comment1146889_342538), if it's still not there after a day, you could ping a CM :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post remains featured in the bulletin even if \[featured\] tag is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297870/post-remains-featured-in-the-bulletin-even-if-featured-tag-is-removed) Even though the question is worded differently, the answers here answer this situation as well.